# Can't drag and drop in Qt Creator

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, qt

I recently installed the system upgrades for my Ubuntu distro (12.10). Since the upgrades, [I can't drag and drop items in Qt Creator](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/48761-QT-Upgraded-Can-t-add-Widgets-to-UI). I found [a solution](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/4544-Can-t-drop-a-widget-in-designer-solution) that requires editing of `xorg.conf`.

My system has no `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file. I tried on a previous install to copy-paste a sample `xorg.conf` and add the required edits, but this prevented me from even booting into a terminal. I now have a fresh install. How would I go about performing these edits without breaking my system? Alternatively, is there any other way to get the Qt Creator functionality back?

**edit** I'm currently using Gnome Shell so the [answer presented here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797159/cant-edit-drag-and-drop-widgets-in-qtcreator) does not help.